# Mac OS X Yosemite: It is possible to disable the animation when switching "spaces"?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-yosemite

Is it possible to disable the animation when switching "spaces"?

The animation is jarring, and isn't really usable if used in high repetition.

Note: this question is specifically for OS X Yosemite